# How to import a RAML file into a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2, raml

I downloaded this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MuleSoftInc.RAMLToolsforNET) from the marketplace to import RAML files into my project. To test the plugin I used a file with the following content:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: REST Services API
version: v1
protocols: [ HTTPS ]
baseUri: http://194.168.1.2:8083/api/v1
mediaType: application/json
types:
  MyEnum:
    enum: [Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4]
  VersionResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      result: integer

/test/get_version:
  post:
    description: Invoke method get_version
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: VersionResponse
      500:
      501:
      503:
```

So I add the file using the plugin, but all that happens is an endless progressbar and nothing gets imported.

Is this a problem with the above RAML content or an issue with the plugin?

Comment: According to your description and codes, I couldn’t find the reason directly. Could you please tell me how you build the client and api server side? As far as I know, the RAML file format could generate by the api. I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-dotnet-tools/wiki/Extract-a-RAML-definition-from-your-Web-app) to re-check your RAML file format.

Comment: @KyleWang I don't want to generate the RAML file from my WebApi. I want to create client code from the RAML file.